# building custom dataset with build_image_data.py for tensorflow inceptionv3 model

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow

I'd like to train my own image data set with tensorflow inception model V3. I am trying to convert my data to TFRecords format. I have created the folders for Training, validation and output folder for tfrecords. I have my labels_file.txt aswell.
When I try to convert the data using this command:

```
bazel-bin/inception/build_image_data 
--train_directory="${TRAIN_DIR}" 
--validation_directory="${VALIDATION_DIR}" 
--output_directory="${OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}" 
--labels_file="${LABELS_FILE}" 
--train_shards=128 
--validation_shards=24 
--num_threads=8
```

I did not get any errors but got a message :

```
Saving results to /tmp/
Determining list of input files and labels from /tmp/.
Found 0 JPEG files across 0 labels inside /tmp/.
Launching 2 threads for spacings: [[0, 0], [0, 0]]
2017-09-14 11:37:47.985543: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-09-14 11:37:47.993902: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-09-14 11:37:47.993969: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-09-14 11:37:48.524331 [thread 1]: Wrote 0 images to /tmp/validation-00001-of-00002
2017-09-14 11:37:48.524490 [thread 1]: Wrote 0 images to 0 shards.
2017-09-14 11:37:48.525079 [thread 0]: Wrote 0 images to /tmp/validation-00000-of-00002
2017-09-14 11:37:48.525175 [thread 0]: Wrote 0 images to 0 shards.
2017-09-14 11:37:49.364996: Finished writing all 0 images in data set.
Determining list of input files and labels from /tmp/.
Found 0 JPEG files across 0 labels inside /tmp/.
Launching 2 threads for spacings: [[0, 0], [0, 0]]
2017-09-14 11:37:49.402218 [thread 0]: Wrote 0 images to /tmp/train-00000-of-00002
2017-09-14 11:37:49.404787 [thread 0]: Wrote 0 images to 0 shards.
2017-09-14 11:37:49.405332 [thread 1]: Wrote 0 images to /tmp/train-00001-of-00002
2017-09-14 11:37:49.405367 [thread 1]: Wrote 0 images to 0 shards.
2017-09-14 11:37:50.406126: Finished writing all 0 images in data set.
```

I used the correct path for all the folders but its not reading the files. Can anyone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my mistake. I forgot to update the classes and examples in imagenet_data.py.